# Log in box keeps popping up in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, windows-authentication

I have a problem with my sharepoint site, when I go to the home page the log in box keeps popping up, I have to click about 3 to  4 times before it goes away, and it does that everytime I go to the home page, all the other pages does not do that.

Can any one please help me out here.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like something wrong with Kerberos authentication. You could re-post your question serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything on your homepage you do not have rights to? Like un-approved images?

Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/version.asp) to see what is causing the authentication requests.

Answer (score 0):

Add the sharepoint url to the Trusted Sites also try enabling "Automatic Logon" under the Local Intranet Zone security settings

cheers,
NK